# Blazor and WebAPI application does not run to debug - Unable to run your project. The "RunCommand" property is not defined

Tags: blazor, webapi

I have a Blazor application running .net standard 2.0 and a WebAPI running in .NET core 3.1 and a standard class library.

The application compiled and ran fine until yesterday when it seemingly just stopped compiling with the error

> Unable to run your project. The "RunCommand" property is not defined.

The output type for both the Blazor and WebAPI is a Console Application and I have multiple startup projects set - WebAPI first and the the Blazor.

I dont think anything has changed to cause this error.

Any ideas what could cause this?

**UPDATE**

Since deleting the obj and bin files, I now get the following error in VS -

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error MSB3073 The command "dotnet
>   "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\3.1.0-preview3.19531.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/monolinker/monolinker.exe"
>   -l none --disable-opt unreachablebodies --verbose --strip-security true --exclude-feature com --exclude-feature sre -v false -c link -u
>   link -b true -d
>   "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\3.1.0-preview3.19531.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/mono/bcl/"
>   -d "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\3.1.0-preview3.19531.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/mono/bcl/Facades/"
>   -d "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\3.1.0-preview3.19531.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/mono/framework/" -o "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\auth\src\HeartOfGreen.BlazorClient\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker/"
>   -x "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.1.0-preview3.19555.2\targets\BuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor.xml"
>   -x "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\auth\src\HeartOfGreen.BlazorClient\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker.descriptor.xml"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\blazored.localstorage\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Blazored.LocalStorage.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\blazorinputfile\0.1.0-preview-00002\lib\netstandard2.0\BlazorInputFile.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization\3.1.0-preview3.19555.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor\3.1.0-preview3.19555.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.httpclient\3.1.0-preview3.19555.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient.dll" -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components\3.1.0-preview3.19555.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.authorization\3.1.0-preview3.19555.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms\3.1.0-preview3.19555.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web\3.1.0-preview3.19555.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting\2.2.7\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.server.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.http\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.metadata\3.1.0-preview3.19555.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Metadata.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.bcl.asyncinterfaces\1.1.0-preview3.19551.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.configuration\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.configuration.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.environmentvariables\2.2.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\3.1.0-preview3.19553.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll" -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\3.1.0-preview3.19553.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.physical\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.filesystemglobbing\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.hosting.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.logging\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\3.1.0-preview3.19553.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.objectpool\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.options\3.1.0-preview3.19553.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll" -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\3.1.0-preview3.19553.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.jsinterop\3.1.0-preview3.19553.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.net.http.headers\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\mono.webassembly.interop\3.1.0-preview3.19553.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Mono.WebAssembly.Interop.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.buffers\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.collections.immutable\1.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.7.0-preview3.19551.4\lib\netstandard2.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource\4.5.1\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\system.memory\4.5.3\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Memory.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\system.numerics.vectors\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll"
>   -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.reflection.metadata\1.6.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.7.0-preview3.19551.4\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\system.text.encodings.web\4.7.0-preview3.19551.4\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll" -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\system.text.json\4.7.0-preview3.19551.4\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks.extensions\4.5.2\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\auth\src\HeartOfGreen.Shared\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\HeartOfGreen.Shared.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\auth\src\HeartOfGreen.BlazorClient\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\HeartOfGreen.BlazorClient.dll""
>   exited with code
>   -532462766.   HeartOfGreen.BlazorClient   C:\Users\Matt.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.1.0-preview3.19555.2\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets   441

Comment: What do you use the standard class library for ?

Comment: @enet it just has the classes and mdoels used in the application, nothing more.

Comment: try to delete *obj, bin, .vs and .vscode* folders

Comment: @aguafrommars I have deleted obj and bin, they got recreated ok but it still doesnt compile. I now get an error which I have added above.

Comment: target netstandard2.1 re remove obj, bin and .vs folders

Comment: @aguafrommars done that, still the same error.

Comment: It looks like you use 3.1.0 : `3.1.0-preview3.19531.1` 1st line error

Comment: Did you update blazor dotnet template ? it should be `3.2.0-preview1.20073.1`